# How to determine the camera pose based on extrinsic parameters

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

Good day Community,

I am currently working on the subject of multiple camera calibration. there is one point that I have not yet understood.

Suppose I have calibrated my separately cameras with N-images on which a checkerboard can be seen in different positions and orientations in the same FOV. After the calibration I get the intrinsic parameters for each camera. Furthermore I get the extrinsic parameters rvec and tvec for each image. Now I want to determine each camera pose wrt to an arbitary world coordinate and then use one camera as a reference for the others. At this point some questions arise:

1. Which of the rvec's and tvec's should I use for the further process?
2. Do I need to average rvec and tvec to determine the camera pose as accurately as possible?

I hope someone can give me some advice.

Comment: the rvecs and tvecs are according to the coordinate system that is defined by the checkerboard. So if you want a global coordinate system, choose the object coordinates according to that coordinate system. E.g. if the first checkerboard-corner is point (0,0,0) and yoz move the the checkerboard 100 units in x dirrction of your global coordinate system, you would have to change the corner point coordinate to (100,0,0). In that case your rvecs and tvecs will be the camera extrinsics wrt the global coordinate system for each of the samples. Currently they are wrt N different coordinate systems.

Comment: a maybe more simple way is to just use the intrinsics from the calibration process. Then use solvePnp function with another calibration pattern position to get the (inverted) camera pose wrt that pattern position, which should be your global coordinate system position.